# Get only all alphabet file extensions

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I am using the following script to find all file extensions from a given path:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path C:\myshellscript -recurse | 
    Select-Object FullName, Extension | 
    ConvertTo-HTML -head $a | 
    Out-File C:\Script\fileextension.htm
```

**Output:**

[image]

But I don't want to display the numeric values, but only the alphabet extensions. All numeric file extension should be blank no extension should be displayed, numeric extension should be avoided

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want hide extension numeric

```
$res=0
gci "C:\myshellscript" -File -Recurse | 
    select FullName , @{N="Extension";E={if (-not [int]::TryParse($_.Extension.Replace(".", ""), [ref]$res) ) {$_.Extension} else {""}}} |
        ConvertTo-HTML -head $a | 
            Out-File C:\Script\fileextension.htm
```

if you want filter extension numeric

```
$res=0
gci "C:\myshellscript" -File -Recurse | where { -not [int]::TryParse($_.Extension.Replace(".", ""), [ref]$res)}
    select FullName , Extension |
        ConvertTo-HTML -head $a | 
            Out-File C:\Script\fileextension.htm
```

Comment: Thank you so much .. you made my day

Answer (score 3):

I added a `Where-Object` cmdlet pipeline which will remove all entries that contains **only** integer. However, I guess extensions like `.7zip`  is valid so it won't remove them:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path C:\myshellscript -recurse | 
    Where-Object { $_.Extension -match '\D+' } |
    Select-Object FullName, Extension | 
    ConvertTo-HTML -head $a | 
    Out-File C:\Script\fileextension.htm
```

Comment: but if i dont need 7 zip extensions what should i  change in script , say for that also thank you

Comment: any ideas can you suggest for having without numeric extension , i need it badly.

Comment: just change the match to: `-match '^\D+$'`

Comment: last thing , i got different scenario now , karaf\system\org\springframework\spring-asm\3.1.4.RELEASE in this case 3.1.4.RELEASE is present how to avoid two or more continous dot before slash

Comment: to be more clear,  if numbers (dot) alphabet comes also it should be removed

Comment: karaf\system\org\springframework\spring-asm\ (after slash) 3.1.4.RELEASE , how to remove numbers (dot) alphabets

Comment: may be in path after last slash if number comes it should removed fully

Comment: This sounds like a directory? So just add the -file switch to the Get-ChildItem cmdlet. Also you should start another question if you still need further help.